# GOLANG: Walk Directory Tree and Process Files -- err = 'no such file or directory

Tags: go

I'm writing a routine to walk a directory tree and create a digital signature (salted-hash) for each file I find.  When testing it I get this weird behavior - if I give the program a root path "above" the directory, the program can walk the tree and print out the file names, but if I try and open the file to read it's bytes, I get the error message "no such file or directory" on the file that the routines found - not sure what gives here.  How can the Walk() routine "see" the file, but ioutil.ReadFile() not be able to find it?

Sample Code:

```
// start with path higher up the tree, say $HOME
func doHashWalk(dirPath string) {
    err := filepath.Walk(dirPath, walkFn)
    // Check err here
}

func walkFn(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) (e error) {

    if !fi.IsDir() {
        // if the first character is a ".", then skip it as it's a hidden file

        if strings.HasPrefix(fi.Name(), ".") {
            return nil
        }

        // read in the file bytes -> get the absolute path
        fullPath, err := filepath.Abs(fi.Name())
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Abs Err: %s", err)
        }

        // THIS ALWAYS FAILED WITH ERROR
        bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fullPath) // <-- (fi.Name() also doesn't work)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Err: %s, Bytes: %d", err, len(bytes))     
        }

        // create the salted hash
        ...
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Short answer is that `fi.Name()` only provides the name of the file, not the path. Use `path` for your abs call which contains both the dirname and the basename of the file.

Answer (score 5):

Try logging the values of `path` vs. `fullPath` inside of `walkFn`.

Using `filepath.Abs()` inside of `walkFn` does not give the result you want: it's resolving a filename relative to the current working directory, instead of the original dirPath.

One option is to resolve the target directory to an absolute path up-front in `doHashWalk`:

```
func doHashWalk(dirPath string) {
    fullPath, err := filepath.Abs(dirPath)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("path error:", err)

        return
    }

    err = filepath.Walk(fullPath, walkFn)

    // check err here
}
```

With that change, the `walkFn` callback will always receive a fully-qualified `path` argument; no need to call `filepath.Abs()` again:

```
func walkFn(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) (e error) {
    // ...

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)

    // ...
}
```

If it's important for your application to see the path of each file relative to the original `dirPath` root, you can sneak that path into the `walkFn` callback via a closure:

```
func doHashWalk(dirPath string) error {

    fullPath, err := filepath.Abs(dirPath)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    callback := func(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        return hashFile(fullPath, path, fi, err)
    }

    return filepath.Walk(fullPath, callback)
}

func hashFile(root string, path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if fi.IsDir() {
        return nil
    }

    rel, err := filepath.Rel(root, path)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.Println("hash rel:", rel, "abs:", path)

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks - forgot about the closures.

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that you're not using the `filepath.Walk` exactly the way it's intended.
You allready get the path to the file from the `path` parameter.

The [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk) might not exactly be abundantly clear but they do say this for filepath.Walk:

> Walk walks the file tree rooted at root, **calling walkFn** for each file or directory in the tree, including root.

So you could shorten `walkFn` to something like this:

```
func walkFn(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) (e error) {
    if !fi.IsDir() {
        bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path) // path is the path to the file.
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Fail")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Walk will take care of not walking up the file-tree via `..` there's no need for you to check for that. Considering the absolute path part I don't really think you need that either, but I make no promises ;)