# Read a golang file and replace word search with uppercase

Tags: file-io, go, str-replace

I am trying to search for or a particular words in the files in a directory and and convert each of its instance in all the file in Uppercase.

I want to keep track of the file where the word was found and how many time it appeared in those file.

So far I am able to read the content of the file.
How do send an argument then from the main function to search through the file and replace those instance into upper case?

This is what I have so far:

```
func visit(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) error {

    if err!=nil{
        return err
     }

     if !!fi.IsDir(){
        return nil //
     }

      matched, err := filepath.Match("*.txt", fi.Name())

      if err !=nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
      }

      if matched{
      read,err:= ioutil.ReadFile(path)
      fmt.Println(read)
      check(err)
      fmt.Println(path) }

  return nil
} 

func main() {

  err := filepath.Walk(".", visit)
}
```

Comment: Which variable is marked as "undefined"?

Comment: i have managed to fix that out. I am now trying to figure out how to pass the string i will be searching and converting to uppercase from the main function so that it is search through the file. @VonC, sorry for the poor description, im kind of new here. thank you for your help

Comment: No problem, but you should fix the formatting, and add a clear question, for us to help.

Comment: This what i just did. Thank you;

Comment: Not really. I tried to format your question a bit better. Tell me if that matches what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable which is seen by a `callback` function literal, used by `filepath.Walk`, as a closure.
See for instance "[GOLANG: Walk Directory Tree and Process Files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20384424/6309)".

```
func main() {

    var yourWord := "a word"

    callback := func(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) error {
            // do something with yourWord!
    }

    filepath.Walk(".", callback)

}
```

That means:

- instead of defining a global function `visit` (which cannot be called with any additional parameters, like `yourWord`)
- you define a `callback` function (**[function literal](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals)**) just before calling `filepath.Walk` with it
  See more at "[Codewalk: First-Class Functions in Go](http://golang.org/doc/codewalk/functions/)"

#### Function literals and closures

> Anonymous functions can be declared in Go.
>   **Function literals are closures: they inherit the scope of the function in which they are declared**.
>   They may refer to variables defined in a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as long as they are accessible.

In your case, the 'callback' function literal will inherit from the variable `yourWord` defined before.

---

Note: the function to call is [`strings.ToUpper()`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ToUpper), not `strings.toUpper()`.

Comment: hmmmm i am not sure i get you. Let us assume, i want to search and replace; that is what i will use fmt.Scanf("%s", &input), and then pass the input to a function. how will i then pass hello in this case?

Comment: @user3841581 ok, I have edited my answer: closure is the answer.

Comment: that is what i did; i defined the callback function in the main function but when i declared my yourwor variable,i get the error unexpected :=

Comment: @user3841581 no, in your question, the callback function, called 'visit', is defined outside main.

Comment: yes i redefined it in the main and i called it before calling the filepath.walk but i did that but now when im trying to pout the variable in toupper, it give me an error : cannot refer to unexported name strings.toUppe this that snippet i wrote :if strings.Contains(string(read), sam){
      fmt.Println("this file contain that word")
      temp:=strings.toUpper(sam)

Comment: @user3841581 you need to edit your question in order to reflect exactly what you see when you have this error: that way, we will be able to help.

Comment: @user3841581 I have edited the answer to reflect the actual name of the function to call: `strings.ToUpper()`, not `strings.toUpper()`

Comment: hmmm actually i still need some light; i can change the word search, but when i read it back, when i check the file it has not changed. it is still lower case

Comment: @user3841581 that would be a new question in order to write a file contentyou modified, then